# student's $t$-distribution

Tags: probability, estimation

Random sample of $457$

Sample mean = $3.59$

Sample standard deviation $1.045$

Confidence interval from $3.49$ to $3.69$

What is the confidence level?

How can I get the answer when sample size is so large?
I tried to find the number from the student's $t$-distribution table but the maximum was $100$.

Is $3.59 + \dfrac{1.045x}{\sqrt{457}} = 3.69$ right? $x$ is what I couldn't find from the table.

Please help.

Comment: You can just do this in R: `2*pt((3.69 - 3.59)/1.045, 457) - 1 = 0.07619427`. It is quite close to the normal result, `2*pnorm((3.69 - 3.59)/1.045) - 1 = 0.07623622`.

Comment: Standard software packages give things beyond what can be found in tables in textbooks.  (So can extensive books of tables published in the first half of the 20th century.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: when the number of degrees of freedom / data points is very large-scale, the $t$ distribution is very close to a normal one.

---

Quoting [link](http://www.statlect.com/ucdstu1.htm),

> A Student's $t$ distribution with mean $\mu$, scale $\sigma^2$ and $n$ degrees of freedom converges in distribution (ie their density functions converge) to a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance  $\sigma^2$ when the number of degrees of freedom $n \to \infty $.

Or from [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution),

> Whereas a normal distribution describes a full population, t-distributions describe samples drawn from a full population; accordingly, the t-distribution for each sample size is different, and the larger the sample, the more the distribution resembles a normal distribution.

From another angle, recall that the $t$ statistic is the $z$ statistic where we replaced the true population standard deviation $\sigma$ by the sample's standard error $s_n$. As $n$ grows, $s_n \to \sigma$ and, intuitively, $t_n \to z \sim N(0,1)$.

---

In your case, what you need to calculate is the cumulative probability (the area under the density curve) of a Student $t_{456}$ distribution between $-t' = \frac{3.49-3.59}{1.045/\sqrt{457}}$ and $t' = \frac{3.69-3.59}{1.045/\sqrt{457}}$.

If you want to use tables (which I find is a good idea for training), take a [$z$ table](https://s3.amazonaws.com/udacity-hosted-downloads/ZTable.jpg) and look for $t' \simeq z' = \frac{3.69-3.59}{1.045/\sqrt{457}} = 2.05$; this gives you a value of $P(z < z') = 0.9798$ (area under the curve excluding the right tail). Given that you want the area under the curve excluding both tails, the value you are looking for is $P(-z' < z < z') = 0.9798 - (1-0.9798) = 0.96$.

If you only have a $t$ table, since you know that $t_n \to z$, just use the bottommost row as an approximation. Using [this one](https://qualityrg4.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/t-table.jpg) (which is particularly handy since it gives values for $df=100$ and $df=1000$ as well as $z^*$), your value of $t_n' = 2.05$ falls very close to the column corresponding to a right-tail area of $0.2$, or a confidence interval of $96\%$. QED

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I still don't get it..I understand the central limit theorem. How can i get the reliability factor

Comment: So the answer is 0.1=z*1.045 ?  z=0.095?

Comment: @Nakhari: is it fine for you?

Comment: Thank you. It does help me